# Shared torrent client between computers on network

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Basically what I have are 2 computers on my network. Both have a torrent client (currently utorrent) and each computer downloads whatever torrents are needed. BUT because most of the torrents I download are on a private tracker, i am running into an issue where if i download the file on 1 computer and then say my roommate doesnt know i did so he downloads the same file and i get a warning for double downloading the same file. I need a way for both of us to have 1 common client that lists all the files that have been downloaded for both of the computers so that we can easily keep track of which files have been downloaded.

Right now i have both completed torrent folders shared on the network and we have to check the folder each time before we download something. This is a big hassle so i want to try to setup something easier.

Comment: run it off a server with something like transmissiond or torrentflux. then you can both use the web interface to queue up and check on stuff, and everything goes into the same shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to run a single torrent client on a single machine you can both access.  This shared access can be accomplished a number of ways, depending on your available hardware and technical abilities.

The first thing I would consider would be setting up a third machine that you can both access.  It could be a cheap netbook, or an old desktop that you aren't using any more. Put it some place out of the way.  You can either walk to that machine to manage your torrents, or better, set up some form of remote access, such as RDP, or a web server, using a web-based torrent client (as suggested by @FrankThomas in comments).

If you're especially technical and/or adventurous, you could install Linux on this machine, which makes network access even easier, as there are web, GUI, and console-based torrent clients for Linux.

If you don't have a third machine you can use, you can decide that only you or your roommate will run a torrent client, and grant the other access via RDP or a web server, as described above.

Comment: Having tested Deluge, qBittorrent and some other opensource client/server torrent software, i had to declare this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) should help you solve the problem.

Deluge is a torrent consists of two parts: *daemon* and *client*. You should run daemon on one of your computers and make it download to a shared folder. Then you can start clients on both computers and connect them to the same daemon. Done.

How it works: Deluge daemon is the part of the program that actually handles downloads, but doesn't provide any user interface. Deluge client doesn't download files itself, but it connects to a daemon and lets you control it.

So basically only one of your computers will be downloading files, but both computers will see what is being downloaded and what's already been downloaded. I guess that's what you're looking for.